# Dynamically appending text to all property names of any object in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider the following object

```java
@Value
public class Example {
    @JsonProperty("StrValue")
    String strValue;
    @JsonProperty("Internal")
    Internal internal;
    
    @Value
    public static class Internal {
        @JsonProperty("InternalValue")
        String internalValue;
    }
}
```

I could get a serialization of this object like

```json
"Example" : {
  "StrValue": "v1",
  "Internal": {
    "InternalValue": "v2"
  }
}
```

However, I need two different versions of this object, one would have the string `First` appended to the name of all properties and the other would have `Second`:

```json
"ExampleFirst" : {
  "StrValueFirst": "v1",
  "InternalFirst": {
    "InternalValueFirst": "v2"
  }
}
```

(And similarly for `Second`)

Note that this should work for nested properties and for any object of any class. Is there an easy way to do this? I feel like this might be the work of `BeanSerializerModifier` or some other custom serialization mechanisms, however, the custom serialization APIs are pretty low-level and the documentation is scarce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since I (kind of) solved it:

First I would make a subclass of `BeanPropertyWriter` such as

```java
   class AppendingPropertyWriter extends BeanPropertyWriter {
        private final BeanPropertyWriter writer;

        public AppendingPropertyWriter(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
            super(writer);
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object bean,
                                     JsonGenerator gen,
                                     SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
            Object value = writer.get(bean);
            gen.writeObjectField(writer.getName() + "First", value);
        }
    }
```

Then add it to the `BeanSerializerModifier` like:

```java
public class AppendingSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {

    @Override
    public List<BeanPropertyWriter> changeProperties(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, List<BeanPropertyWriter> beanProperties) {
        for (int i = 0; i < beanProperties.size(); i++) {
            BeanPropertyWriter writer = beanProperties.get(i);
            beanProperties.set(i, new AppendingPropertyWriter(writer));
        }
        return beanProperties;
    }
}
```

Then you'd have to put it into your `ObjectMapper` like:

```java
        var serializerModifier = new AppendingSerializerModifier();
        var sf = BeanSerializerFactory.instance.withSerializerModifier(serializerModifier);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        mapper.setSerializerFactory(sf);
```

Then this mapper achieves the intended effect. However this seems to bypass some other modules I added like `JavaTimeModule` and throw an exception with them. So if anyone has a solution to that I'd be grateful.

EDIT: Fixed it! Turns out I needed to serialize the object as

```java
        @Override
        public void serializeAsField(Object bean,
                                     JsonGenerator gen,
                                     SerializerProvider prov) throws Exception {
            Object value = writer.get(bean);
            prov.defaultSerializeField(writer.getName() + "First", value, gen);
        }
```

And then be sure to register the `JavaTime` module after setting the factory